# Save bar plot in subplot

Tags: matlab, save-as, subplot

I want to save my plotted figure in MATLAB to a `fig` file. Currently I'm using the following code:

```
hf1 = figure();
p1=uipanel('Parent',hf1);
a1=subplot(2,1,1,'Parent',p1);
%b1=plot(a1,1:9);
b1=bar(a1,1:9);
a2=subplot(2,1,2,'Parent',p1);
b2=bar(a2,1:9);
%b2=plot(a2,1:9);
hf2 = figure('Visible', 'on');   
hAxes = copyobj(findobj(p1,'Type','Axes'), hf2);
saveas(hf2,'case2.fig','fig');
```

But then I get the following error:

> ??? Error using ==> getProxyValueFromHandle at 15
>   Input must be a valid handle.
>
> Error in ==> plotedit at 91
>                  [varargout{1:nargout}] = feval(args{:});
>
> Error in ==> specgraph.barseries.preserialize at 10
>   peerVals = plotedit({'getProxyValueFromHandle',hPeers});
>
> Error in ==> hgsaveStructDbl at 81
>          olddata{i} = {hh,preserialize(hh)};
>
> Error in ==> hgsave at 63
>      hgS = hgsaveStructDbl(h, SaveAll);
>
> Error in ==> saveasfig at 7
>   hgsave( h, name );
>
> Error in ==> saveas at 126
>      feval( ['saveas' format], h, name )
>
> Error in ==> testbar at 11
>   saveas(hf2,'case2.fig','fig');

But when I replace the `bar` with `plot` in the code (I commented them out now^^), then I can save the figure successfully.

The version I'm using is MATLAB R2010a.

Comment: Do you really need to copy the figure first to a new one? why don't you just use `saveas(hf1,'case2.fig','fig');` works here!

Comment: Very strange. Perhaps you should file a support ticket with MathWorks. Or try to upgrade to the recent version first.

Comment: Mathworks Bug Report [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/469597)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code

```
b=bar(a1,1:9,'hist');
```

instead of

```
b=bar(a1,1:9);
```